# Is there a way for a input box to run a function when the user presses the enter key?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I run the function when the user clicks a button next to the input box. How can I make it run either by the user clicking enter or the user clicking the button.

Here is the code that I'm currently using:

```
 <input id="input" type="text">
 <button onclick="exampleFunction()">Run Function</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have jQuery, bind the function to the `submit` handler, like this:

```js
$("#myForm").submit(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  myFunction();
});
```

Alternatively, you could bind the function to the `keypress` event, like this:

```js
$('#textbox').keypress(function(event){

 var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
 if(keycode == '13'){
  doStuff();
 }

});
```

To use jQuery, simply include this code before any JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See also: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-check-if-an-enter-key-is-pressed-with-jquery/

Comment: @Tler No problem.  Always happy to help!